# I think that "config" and "configuration" tags could be merged

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

As the title says, [config](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/config) and [configuration](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/configuration) maybe could be merged.

Answer (score 1):

Done; [config](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/config) now points to [configuration](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/configuration)